# Filter query through an ID in Django

Tags: python, django, filter

I know this is a common to ask but I'm just confused, what is the best way to filter data from one table to another table, the case is I want to filter the `name` of category1 and category2 table through an ID based on the image shown below, It's very helpful for me to use this kind of implementation.

It same like this

```
Select title ,description, category1_tbl.name, category2_tbl.name from main_tbl....... JOIN TWO TABLES
```

**views.py**

```
task_tbl.objects.get(category1_id=category1_tbl.objects.get(id))
```

[image]

**models**

```
class main_tbl(models.Model):
  category1 = models.ForeignKey(category1_tbl, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
  category2 = models.ForeignKey(category2_tbl, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
  title = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True, null=True)
  description = models.CharField(max_length=1500,blank=True, null=True)
  requested_by = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True, null=True)
  path = models.CharField(max_length=1000,blank=True, null=True)
  date_requested = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
  status = models.IntegerField(max_length=60, default=0, null=True)

class category1_tbl(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True, null=True)
  isactive = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True, null=True)
  created =  models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
  path = models.CharField(max_length=1000,blank=True, null=True)
  modify = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
  created_by = models.CharField(max_length=1000,blank=True, null=True)

class category2_tbl(models.Model):
  category1 = models.ForeignKey(category1_tbl, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
  priority = models.ForeignKey(priority_tbl, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True, null=True)
  isactive = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True, null=True)
  created =  models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
  modify = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
  created_by = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True, null=True)
```

**EDIT** I already tried this before but the question is how can I filter
this to another table? through getting ID from this query

```
id_to_filter = 7
main_objs = main_tbl.objects.filter(category1__id=id_to_filter)
```

**What I've tried** which is returns me an error

```
id_to_filter = 7
main_objs = main_tbl.objects.filter(id=id_to_filter)

getId = main_objs.category1_id

second_table = category1_tbl.objects.filter(category1__id=getId)
result = second_table.name
```

**Let say** the output of the `getId` is `1` then I need to match again to the second table and finally getting the name of it through result variable

Comment: post your two models.The double underscore allows you to filter on a related table. See examples at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

Comment: @AMG Thanks for your response I have posted my models, but still I didn't get the query, please help

Comment: Is somebody knows about this? I'm out of option also I read documentation but I still not get it

Comment: Have you figured this out yet? It is unclear what you are trying to do. Do you have a value for name and want to find something in `main_tbl` that has a category with that name?

Comment: @AMG No, I still not figure this yet, Yes it has a value I just want to retrieve all the list of the table above and get the actual name of each category, need help

Answer (score 0):

Django manages joining the tables for you and knows how to based on your ForeignKey fields.

If you want to filter on a value for name in each of the category tables, you could use an 'or' clause by [using the Q function do make a more complex `or` lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects), something like the following. Note the use of the double underscore to get to the `name` field of the related table. As a side note, you should [start each word of your class/model names with an upper case](https://realpython.com/python-pep8/#naming-styles) and remove the underscore. It is the generally agreed upon style, and in [django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/#model-style) will remove some confusion later when scanning your queries.

```
from django.db.models import Q

name_to_filter = "carl"
main_objs = main_tbl.objects.filter(Q(category1__name=name_to_filter) |
                            Q(category2__name=name_to_filter))
```

If you needed to only return records where the name was required to be in both category 1 and 2, there would be no need for the `or` clause and you can use the default method of [filtering which 'ands' everything together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.filter).

```
name_to_filter = "carl"
main_objs = main_tbl.objects.filter(category1__name=name_to_filter,
                            category2__name=name_to_filter)
```

**EDIT**
If you know a category id, as suggested in your comment, you can filter by that. The filter creates the where clauses. The `main_tbl` [has a field for the id in the categories](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#database-representation) so you can query that directly like:

```
id_to_filter = 7
main_objs = main_tbl.objects.filter(category1_id=id_to_filter)
```

or if you want to force a join you can probably do the double underscore method (not sure why one would want that in this case though)

```
id_to_filter = 7
main_objs = main_tbl.objects.filter(category1__id=id_to_filter)
```

Note that in the filters, you use the name of the field in the main_tbl, not the actual names of the tables they reference.

**Edit 2 After your question was updated**
I think you need to think about things in a different way. You need to determine or describe if you want a list of names from one of those categories or if you need to display them on a template. If you want a JsonResponse, provide what the Json payload should look like. For example, if you want a flat list of the names in the view there are tools for that like [values_list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#values-list):

```
names = main_tbl.objects.filter(id=1).values_list(category1__name, flat=True)
```

but if you want to display things from the main_tbl and categories, pass the queryset to the template. You'd have something like this in the view. Let Django do the work of creating the joins between the tables, that's the strength of the Django [ORM](https://www.fullstackpython.com/object-relational-mappers-orms.html).

```
main_objs = main_tbl.objects.filter(id=1)
context = {'main_objs': main_objs}
return render(request, "your_template.html", context)
```

and in the `your_template.html` something like:

```
{% for cat1 in main_objs.category1_set.all %}
    {{ cat1.name }}<br />
{% endfor %}
```

You need to define what you are trying to do. I have a feeling you may be trying to make things simpler with names like "main_tbl" but you should include in these posts exactly what is is you are trying to do. There may be a better way someone can suggest to achieve what you are after. Based on your post, `main_tbl` might be a task list; if so, leave named as such so people can better conceptualize the problem in real terms.

Comment: but I wan t to get the name through an ID which is I think it should uses WHERE clauses

Comment: what id do you have?

Comment: do you want to display the names in a template, or do you need the names in the view?

Comment: Thanks for your response, Honestly I want to display names in the template or html but firstly I think firstly I need to display it in view through print using `JsonResponse`

Comment: Thanks for your response I've added some preference on my question just to clearly understand the result, hope anyone can help me